# How do I deal with a column name/field name 'time@timestamp' in MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, datetime, etl, data-cleaning

I have imported machine logs coming from data collection devices, transferred by easybuilder pro. So far, in terms of cleaning the data and formatting for correct data types has been straightforward.

However, I have run into an issue with a column name of 'time@timestamp' SQL I've tried doesn't seem to work because of the column name and workbench thinking it's a clause instead of a field name.

**The data is recording for a 24hr period starting at midnight for this field, therefore, is there a way to delete 'time@timestamp' column after adding the values that are in said column to an ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN?**

Tried ALTER TABLE *the name of my table* ADD COLUMN *the name of my new column* DATETIME AFTER *time@timestamp*

Same can be said for RENAME, CHANGE, and DROP clauses (DROP only to get rid of the created columns if needed).

Really racking my brain on this one so any help would greatly appreciated. Bye for now.

Comment: I'm a little unclear of the problem.  Are you seeing an error?  Remember that you can put backticks around a column name to ensure that it's treated as an identifier, not a value

Comment: I am indeed, currently trying to run this:
ALTER TABLE my_table_name 
ADD COLUMN time_12am DATETIME AFTER 'time@timestamp';
It says the 'time@timestamp' is incorrect, code 1064.

Comment: Try using backticks `\``, not quote marks `'`.  Quote marks are for literal string values, backticks are for identifiers

Comment: That's going in my notes for sure... Thank you very much, that fixed it.